# NLog config settings renderer not working as expected

Tags: nlog

Just uploaded a test case app - https://github.com/lsfera/NLog-Demo-cases/tree/master/Net5

I have a configuration section in my [appsettings](https://github.com/lsfera/NLog-Demo-cases/blob/master/Net5/Console/appsettings.json) to provide environment specific parameters.

```
  "LoggingContext": {
    ..
    "ApplicationName": "cool-app",
    "SyslogUrl": "syslog.server.url"
  }
```

Everything works fine - also the configSetting layout renderer part - except it doesn't work as (I) expected.

```
     "targets": {
      "file": {
        "type": "AsyncWrapper",
        "target": {
          "wrappedFile": {
            "type": "File",
            "fileName": "${configsetting:item=LoggingContext.ApplicationName}.log"
.......
```

File name is correctly replaced - as expected - resulting in "cool-app.log".
But when it comes to syslog section:

```
"syslog": {
...
      "messageSend": {
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "tcp": {
            "server": "${configsetting:item=LoggingContext.SyslogUrl}"
...
```

server is left in raw format - "${configsetting:item=LoggingContext.SyslogUrl}"

Same issue with target of type "Http" with  "URL" parameter "${configsetting:item=LoggingContext.AlertServiceUrl}"

What's wrong in this configuration?
Example project contains the [nlog.config](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lsfera/NLog-Demo-cases/master/Net5/Console/nlog.config) xml version - too convenience

Comment: Think this is the issue: https://github.com/luigiberrettini/NLog.Targets.Syslog/blob/ccd1b7f82125c0b64bc7527efaf7e5ccf7afd7a4/src/NLog.Targets.Syslog/Settings/TcpConfig.cs#L27 (Should have been `public Layout Server`)

Comment: Created https://github.com/luigiberrettini/NLog.Targets.Syslog/pull/271 lets see what happens

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen
Same issue on "http" target too - assuming also this https://github.com/DarekDan/NLog.Targets.HTTP/blob/master/NLog.Targets.Http/HTTP.cs#L65  is a good candidate

Comment: @Isfera Have added a comment to https://github.com/DarekDan/NLog.Targets.HTTP/issues/5 about how it could be solved for Http-target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NLog.Targets.Syslog ver. 6.0.3](https://github.com/luigiberrettini/NLog.Targets.Syslog/releases/tag/v6.0.3) has been [released to nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.Syslog/) with [Layout-support for Server-property](https://github.com/luigiberrettini/NLog.Targets.Syslog/pull/271).

NLog.Targets.HTTP ver. 1.0.16 has been [released to nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.HTTP) with Layout-support for Headers (Right now there is a bug so one have to explict assign `Authorization=""` on the target).

```xml
<target type="HTTP"
        name="ws"
        Method='POST'
        URL="https://log-api.eu.newrelic.com/log/v1"
        ContentType='application/json'
        Accept='application/json'
        Authorization=''>
    <header name="X-License-Key" value="${environment:LICENSE_KEY}"/>
</target>
```